# Please explain this Java loop logic error

Tags: java, loops, logic-error

I am expecting the below loop logic to bring cookies to 504 before printing 42. The program will run but nothing is returned.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                
    int cookies = 500;
    while(cookies % 12 != 0) {
        if (cookies % 12 == 0) {
            System.out.println(cookies/12);
        }           
        cookies++;
    } 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The if condition is never true inside the while loop. It true after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch this to a do/while to make it work. It will check the if statement first, increment your variable, then check the condition.

Comment: This won't make any difference in this case. It still wouldn't display anything since the loop condition will fall true before the `if` condition. The loop would end **before** the `if` statement even comes int play in either case. Bottom line...the `if` block shouldn't even be in the loop, just display the goodies **after** (outside) the loop: `System.out.println("Cookies = " + cookies + " | Value = " + cookies / 12);`

Comment: Thank you both, DevilsHnd was correct in that there was no need for the if statement, all I needed to do was print out the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Condition 'cookies % 12 == 0' is always 'false' !

So it never prints anything!

This code will print out `42`:

```
        int cookies = 500;
        while (cookies % 12 != 0) {
            cookies++;
            if (cookies % 12 == 0) {
                System.out.println(cookies/12);
            }
        }
```

Reason: if you put the `cookies++` at the end, then whenever `cookies % 12 == 0`, it breaks the `while` loop immediately, so it won't print anything.